# Why do some objects appear on top of others, and not always like that?

Tags: c#, winforms

I created 2 empty labels, using winforms, to cover some groupboxes
They were created exactly the same way, but they dont behave the same way

The first one:

[image]

The second one:

[image]

The first covers everything, the second one only covers one groupbox, and displays the other two.

I tried the right click+ send to back /send to front, but I believe this doesn't mean anything in the code, it only purpose is to allow you to visualize better what you are placing in your form, I guess.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: "Send to back/Send to front" is not useful only in the Designer. It is also valid during runtime.

Comment: I tried sending both labels to back, and to front, and they still behave differently, what causes this?

Comment: I tought of it, but i  wanted to understand why it was not behaving like i wanted.

Comment: I had to send the groupboxes backward to solve it, thanks @Otiel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groubox, Panel, TabPage etc are containers in which we keep controls. Form itself is also a container..

When you drag a label or any other control to place in a form, and if you want to hide the other controls, you should place the label in the form itself and the label should not become child of any of the groupBoxes.

For that the left top corner of the label you drag should not go inside any of the groupBoxes. This is only when you drag. If you want to position at a point inside groupBox, then Drag the control outside the groupBox and then use keyboard arrows to position, this will not let the control to become child of the groupBox. You can also set position on property window.